# Extract OpenGL raw RGB(A) texture data from png data stored in NSData using libpng on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, libpng, premultiplied-alpha

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to using a built-in method on iOS to extract 32 bit RGBA data from a PNG file without losing the alpha channel [reference](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.no/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html). Therefore, [some people](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/11/07/loading-a-png-as-texture-in-opengl-using-libpng/) have been using [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to extract their OpenGL textures. However, all the examples have required the png file to be loaded from a file. Assuming these textures are imported over a network connection, they would have to be saved to files from `NSData` and then read. What is the best way to extract raw PNG data into raw OpenGL RGBA texture data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a category which solves this problem using the customization capabilities of libpng. Posted a gist here: https://gist.github.com/joshcodes/5681512

Hopefully this helps someone else who needs to know how this is done. The essential part is creating a method

```
void user_read_data(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep data, png_size_t length)
{
    void *nsDataPtr = png_get_io_ptr(png_ptr);
    ReadStream *readStream = (ReadStream*)nsDataPtr;
    memcpy(data, readStream->source + readStream->index, length);
    readStream->index += length;
}
```

and using

```
// init png reading
png_set_read_fn(png_ptr, &readStream, user_read_data);
```

as a custom read method.